# Run Multiple queries and one time

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-update, multi-query

Ok!  I have a script that is part of a live auction and my code is not all working and I am at the end of my rope!  The below code is the two ways I have tried with no luck:

> ```
>   <? if(isset($_GET['golive'])) { 
>
>   $id = $_POST['id'];
>   $totalamount = $_POST['amount'];
>   $ordernumber = $_POST['ordernumber'];
>
>   mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBpassword") or  die(mysql_error()); 
>   mysql_select_db("DBname") or die(mysql_error(header('Location: live_auction.php?ordermun=error'))); 
>
>   mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction_bundle 
>    (`purchaser_id`,`amount`,`order_number`,`date`) VALUES (".$id.",".$totalamount.",".$ordernumber.",NOW())
>   UPDATE auction_products SET order_number=".$ordernumber." WHERE on_now=1;              
>   UPDATE auction_products SET sold=1 WHERE on_now=1;
>   UPDATE auction_products SET on_now=3 WHERE on_now=1"); 
>   header('Location: live_auction.php?ordermun='.$ordernumber.'');
>
>   } 
>   ?>
> ```

I Also Tried

> ```
>   <? if(isset($_GET['golive'])) { 
>
>   $id = $_POST['id'];
>   $totalamount = $_POST['amount'];
>   $ordernumber = $_POST['ordernumber'];
>
>   mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBpassword") or  die(mysql_error()); 
>   mysql_select_db("DBname") or die(mysql_error(header('Location: live_auction.php?ordermun=error'))); 
>
>   mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction_bundle 
>    (`purchaser_id`,`amount`,`order_number`,`date`) VALUES (".$id.",".$totalamount.",".$ordernumber.",NOW()");
>
>   mysql_query("UPDATE auction_products SET order_number=".$ordernumber." WHERE on_now=1");              
>   mysql_query("UPDATE auction_products SET sold=1 WHERE on_now=1");
>   mysql_query("UPDATE auction_products SET on_now=3 WHERE on_now=1"); 
>   header('Location: live_auction.php?ordermun='.$ordernumber.'');
>
>   } 
>   ?>
> ```

This second one was able to change the auction_products table but still would not INSERT and other query.  What am I missing.  I need all four of those to happen at the time that the golive button is clicked.

Comment: You probably need to wrap the values in your query in single quotes. If you add `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of each query, you can see exactly what the database is returning if the query doesn't work - you're currently assuming that everything always works.

Comment: are you getting any error.

Comment: You should stop using mysql_* functions and switch to mysqli or PDO (you could also abstract with a tool like Doctrine). Also, you should never pass user inputs directly into the text of your query. You're begging for a sql injection attack. If you switch to mysqli or PDO you can do parameterized queries helps with the sql injection problem.

Comment: `die(mysql_error(header('Location: live_auction.php?ordermun=error')))` <- makes no sense. You can't pass a header to that function. Also try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` in production.

Comment: You guys are correct I am open to sql injection attacks so I will work on that.  My main issue is that the first INSERT query does not work... ever!  Even when it is alone it will not work and I dont know why.

Comment: @jessepfieffer - if you added `or die(mysql_error())` at the end, you'd know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert query doesn't work because your forgot a ) at the end.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction_bundle 
   (`purchaser_id`,`amount`,`order_number`,`date`) VALUES (".$id.",".$totalamount.",".$ordernumber.",NOW()");
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction_bundle 
   (`purchaser_id`,`amount`,`order_number`,`date`) VALUES (".$id.",".$totalamount.",".$ordernumber.",NOW())");
```